# If I have let's say a finite number of points in a metric space, and lets say that space has a couple of different metrics.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

If I have let's say a finite number of points in a metric space, and lets say that space has a couple of different metrics defined. Is the diameter of a subset unique with respect to the two most "distant" points. To clarify in example:
Say I have the following metrics in space $X:$
$$d_1(x,y), d_2(x,y) , d_3(x,y); \ \ \ x,y \in X$$

Now $$\text{diam}_{d_i} A=\sup_{\text{x,y} \in A} d_i(x,y)$$

My question is are these x,y points unique akka the same for $d_1, d_2, d_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $A = (1,0)$, $B=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) $ , $C = (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ and $D=(-1,0)$

Take $d_1((x,y),(x',y')) = |x-x'|+|y-y'|$ and $d_2 = \sup( |x-x'|,|y-y'|)$

For $d_1$, the diameter is realized for B and C and for $d_2$ the diameter is realized for A and D

Answer (score 0):

No. You could have a metric space consisting of finite set of points (but more than one) in $\mathbb R$. With the usual metric, the diameter of this set is the largest point minus the smallest point. Under the discrete metric, the diameter is 1, and could correspond to any pair of distinct points.